# Running Functions From a Library File

Tags: javascript, xml, html, blackberry-webworks

I am developing a blackberry app and need a notification feature to bring up an alert on the home screen. The site I am using is:

https://github.com/blackberry/WebWorks-Community-APIs/tree/master/Smartphone/notification

which requires the use of an XML library file. I have never used a library file before with HTML so I am completely confused on what to do. I followed the steps on **"How to configure the extension for use"** and I have added the features tag to my configuration file. However, I have no idea on how to use the following code:

```
function startTasks() {
    webworks.notification.register ( "com.demo.myappname" , "My Application Name" )
}

function fireEvent() {
    webworks.notification.fire ( "com.demo.myappname" )
}

function cancelEvent() {
    webworks.notification.cancel ( "com.demo.myappname" )
}
```

In my app package I have a **"listener.html"** which needs to start the notification if certain conditions are true (done by my javascript). I don't know how to "launch" this notification procedure though. In my JS file do I run `startTasks()` then `fireEvent()` to properly start the notification alert?

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!